# Error: Error in Scenario File "smartML/michelson_base/typing.ml", line 206, characters 27-33: Assertion failed

Tags: smartpy

i was writing a HTLC contract and using a scenario when this error shows up: Error: Error in Scenario
File "smartML/michelson_base/typing.ml", line 206, characters 27-33: Assertion failed .
This is the code.

```
class HashTimedLockedContract(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(deadline = sp.none, committer = sp.none , verifier = sp.none, hash = sp.none)

    @sp.entry_point
    def commit(self, deadline, verifier, hash):
        #save into data
        self.data.deadline = sp.some(sp.level + deadline)
        self.data.verifier = sp.some(verifier)
        self.data.hash = sp.some(hash)
        
        self.data.committer = sp.some(sp.sender)

    @sp.entry_point
    def reveal(self, word):
        #hash
        bytes = sp.pack(word) 
        hash = sp.keccak(bytes) #created
        sp.verify(self.data.hash == sp.some(hash), "Wrong word") #checked

        #transfer collateral to committer
        sp.send(self.data.committer.open_some(), sp.balance)


    @sp.entry_point
    def timeout(self):
        #check if deadline is reached and if sender is the verifier
        sp.verify(self.data.deadline <= sp.some(sp.level), "Deadline not reached")

        #transfer collateral to verifier
        sp.send(self.data.verifier.open_some(), sp.balance)

        
    

@sp.add_test(name = "HTLC")
def testHTLC():
    #set scenario
    sc = sp.test_scenario()
    #create object HashTimedLockedContract
    htlc = HashTimedLockedContract()
    #start scenario
    sc += htlc

    #create users
    sofia = sp.test_account("sofia")
    pippo = sp.test_account("pippo")

    #create hash
    bytes = sp.pack("ciao")
    hash = sp.keccak(bytes)
    #first commit
    htlc.commit(sp.record(deadline = sp.nat(10) , verifier = sofia.address, hash = hash)).run(sender = pippo, amount = sp.tez(1000))
    #reveal after 50 rounds
    #htlc.reveal("ciao").run(sender = sofia)
    #timeout after 100 rounds
    htlc.timeout().run(level = 1000)
```

If i remove the # on the `htlc.reveal...` everything goes without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem, set the type of `word` before packing it.

```
@sp.entrypoint
def reveal(self, word):
    sp.set_type(word, sp.TString)
```

The error message can be improved in a future version.

Tip: Gradually comment out or remove sections of your code until you can no longer eliminate any more elements while still encountering the issue. This process will aid you in pinpointing the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks! It works